# How to display Dynamic pivot table using php mysql

Tags: dynamic, pivot

I have this dynamic pivot table code that successfully generate my pivot table in sql. But am finding it very difficult to display the dynamic pivot table on my webpage using php. Please i need your help, any one with the solution should please help me, i have have been on this for three weeks no success, i have search google to my best level but no solution.

`SET @sql := NULL;
SET @columns := NULL;

SET @columns := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("SUM(CASE WHEN `subject_title`='",subject_title,"' THEN ass_1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN `subject_title`='",subject_title,"' THEN ass_2 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN `subject_title`='",subject_title,"' THEN exam ELSE 0 END) AS '",subject_title,"'") SEPARATOR ',') FROM (SELECT DISTINCT `subject_title` AS subject_title FROM score,subject) sbj);

SELECT @columns;

SET @sql := CONCAT("SELECT td.stu_id,
td.name,",@columns,"FROM score AS ts
JOIN student AS td JOIN subject AS tu ON ts.scostu_id=td.stu_id AND ts.scosbj_id=tu.subject_id
GROUP BY td.stu_id,
td.name;");

SELECT @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`

**Result of the above dynamic pivot code**

stu_id  name    MATHEMATICS   ENGLISH  BASIC SC.  SOCIAL ST.
2   DANIEL AGBOJE   64  67  0      0
3   SOLOMOM BRIGHT  60  73  0      0
4   GLADYS AGBOJE   64  86  0      0
5   UKAREEJIT URIEL 50  65  0      0

**Am joining three table together**

**1. student table**
SELECT * FROM `student`

stu_id  name    gender  contact stuclas_id  schstu_id   status
2   DANIEL AGBOJE   MALE    7035730526  1   TCS101  Activate
3   SOLOMOM BRIGHT  FEMALE  703456978   1   TCS101  Activate
4   GLADYS AGBOJE   Female  08033414634 1   TCS101
5   UKAREEJIT URIEL Female  07035730526 1   TCS101  Activate

**2. score table**
SELECT * FROM `score`

score_id    scostu_id   scoclas_id  scosbj_id   scosec_id   schsco_id   scotech_id  asign_id    ass_1   ass_2   ass_3   exam
1   2   1   1   1   TCS101  3   1   10  14      40
2   3   1   1   1   TCS101  3   1   10  15      35
3   4   1   1   1   TCS101  3   1   12  12      40
4   5   1   1   1   TCS101  3   1   13  2       35
5   2   1   2   1   TCS101  2   2   10  12      45
6   3   1   2   1   TCS101  2   2   10  13      50
7   4   1   2   1   TCS101  2   2   15  16      55
8   5   1   2   1   TCS101  2   2   13  17      35

**3. subject table**
SELECT * FROM `subject`

subject_id  subject_title   schsbj_id
1   MATHEMATICS TCS101
2   ENGLISH LANGUAGE    TCS101
3   BASIC SCIENCE   TCS101
4   SOCIAL STUDIES  TCS101

**I Beg for your help.**

I have not try anything yet because i dont know how to go about it. I need help.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Execute the Pivot Query and Fetch Data:**

> Execute the dynamic pivot query and fetch the result set using PHP's
> MySQL functions or a database abstraction library like PDO.

```
$pivotQuery = "/* please enter your dynamic pivot query in here */";
$pivotResult = mysqli_query($connection, $pivotQuery);

if ($pivotResult) {
    // Fetch data from the result set
    $pivotData = mysqli_fetch_all($pivotResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

2. **Prepare Data for Display:**

   ```
   $formattedData = array();
        foreach ($pivotData as $row) {
           $formattedData[$row['stu_id']]['name'] = $row['name'];
           foreach ($row as $subject => $score) {
               if ($subject != 'stu_id' && $subject != 'name') {
                   $formattedData[$row['stu_id']][$subject] = $score;
               }
           }
    }
   ```
3. **HTML Table Generation:**

echo '';
echo 'Student Name';

```
// Generate table header for subjects
$subjects = array_keys($formattedData[key($formattedData)]);
foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
    echo '<th>' . $subject . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

// Generate table rows
foreach ($formattedData as $student) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $student['name'] . '</td>';
    foreach ($subjects as $subject) {
        echo '<td>' . $student[$subject] . '</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But am still having issues. The code is not giving me what i want. Please need more clarity. Thanks